# Python - Group a list of dicts by key value, count separate key value as dict?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to group up the name key values here as a key for a dict value, and count the source value as a key for said parent key, and have the count value with as its value.

```
data = [
{'name':'Gill', 'source':'foo'},
{'name':'Gill', 'source':'foo'},
{'name':'Gill', 'source':'foo'},
{'name':'Gill', 'source':'bar'},
{'name':'Gill', 'source':'bar'},
{'name':'Gill', 'source':'bar'},
{'name':'Gill', 'source':'bar'},
{'name':'Gill', 'source':'bar'},
{'name':'Dave', 'source':'foo'},
{'name':'Dave', 'source':'foo'},
{'name':'Dave', 'source':'foo'},
{'name':'Dave', 'source':'foo'},
{'name':'Dave', 'source':'egg'},
{'name':'Dave', 'source':'egg'},
{'name':'Dave', 'source':'egg'},
{'name':'Dave', 'source':'egg'},
{'name':'Dave', 'source':'egg'},
{'name':'Dave', 'source':'egg'},
{'name':'Dave', 'source':'egg'}
]
```

How do I achieve the below output?

`{'Gill': {'foo':3, 'bar':5}, 'Dave': {'foo':4, 'egg':7}}`

I think it may be possible with a 1 liner...

Comment: Have you tried searching this site first?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to *group* by names, then [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to *count* the source categories belonging to each name:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import groupby

f = lambda x: x['name']
dct = {k: Counter(d['source'] for d in g) for k, g in groupby(data, f)}
print(dct)
# {'Gill': Counter({'bar': 5, 'foo': 3}), 'Dave': Counter({'egg': 7, 'foo': 4})}
```

Comment: Of course, this assumes that the data is sorted by the `'name'` key.

Comment: Thank you, this is great. However for my actual dataset, it has a lot more keys than 'name' and 'source' which I haven't mentioned here (I thought it'd be fine), I may need to strip it down to just the two. But the groupby(data, f) seems to create problems with it, is there a way to make this work if a 3rd key was introduced, but have it disregard said key? (I am being picky)

Comment: @Slopax I don't see how a third key would create a problem if you don't actually need it.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye I am mistaken, having just 2 keys as shown here in my example seems to produce different results, very strange. That's a headache for tomorrow!

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously not a one-liner, but is simple and pretty straight forward. Would work for any number of values.

```py
results = {}
key = 'name'
for line in data:
    tracked_key = line[key]
    results.setdefault(tracked_key, {})
    for k, v in line.iteritems():
        if k == key:
            continue
        results[tracked_key].setdefault(v, 0)
        results[tracked_key][v] += 1
```